# Python -BeautifulSoup - How to target nth child and print the text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape the "Biggest Gainers" list of coins on https://coinmarketcap.com/

How do I access the nth child (Biggest Gainers) in the div `class_ = 'sc-1rmt1nr-0 sc-1rmt1nr-2 iMyvIy'`

I managed to get the data from the "Trending" section but having trouble targeting the "Biggest Gainers" top 3 text items.

I get AttributeError: `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'p'`

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests


source = requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

section = soup.find(class_='sc-1rmt1nr-0 sc-1rmt1nr-2 iMyvIy')

#List the top 3 Gainers 
for top_gainers in section.find_all(class_='sc-16r8icm-0 sc-1uagfi2-0 bdEGog sc-1rmt1nr-1 eCWTbV')[1]:
    top_gainers = top_gainers.find(class_='sc-1eb5slv-0 iworPT')
    top_coins = top_gainers.p.text
    print(top_coins)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `:nth-of-type` to locate the "Biggest Gainers" parent `div`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup
d = soup(requests.get('https://coinmarketcap.com/').text, 'html.parser')
bg = d.select_one('div:nth-of-type(2).sc-16r8icm-0.sc-1uagfi2-0.bdEGog.sc-1rmt1nr-1.eCWTbV')
data = [{'rank':i.select_one('span.rank').text, 
         'name':i.select_one('p.sc-1eb5slv-0.iworPT').text,
          'change':i.select_one('span.sc-27sy12-0.gLZJFn').text}
        for i in bg.select('div.sc-1rmt1nr-0.sc-1rmt1nr-4.eQRTPY')]
```

Output:

```
[{'rank': '1', 'name': 'Tenset', 'change': '1308.72%'}, {'rank': '2', 'name': 'Burn To Earn', 'change': '421.82%'}, {'rank': '3', 'name': 'Aigang', 'change': '329.63%'}]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using this method for now, until I wrap my head around the others! Massively appreciate the help!

Answer (score 2):

I would avoid those dynamic classes and instead use -:soup-contains and combinators to first locate desired block via text, then with the combinators specify the relationship of the final elements to extract info from.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd

soup = bs(requests.get("https://coinmarketcap.com/").text, "lxml")
biggest_gainers = []

for i in soup.select(
    'div[color=text]:has(span:-soup-contains("Biggest Gainers")) > div ~ div'
):
    biggest_gainers.append(
        {
            "rank": int(i.select_one(".rank").text),
            "currency": i.select_one(".alias").text,
            "% change": f"{i.select_one('.icon-Caret-up').next_sibling}",
        }
    )

gainers = pd.DataFrame(biggest_gainers)
gainers
```

Comment: On the same wavelength, just a bit slower with my answer +1

Comment: Thanks for the help, QHarr. I commented on HedgeHog's post stating that I'd have to do a bit more research on the select() function as I'm having trouble understanding the values you've targeted. I think I just have to get accustomed to the syntax. 

Would you also suggest veering away from using find() and find_all()? I noticed no one used them.

Comment: The values I have selected are by class. "." at the start is a css class selector. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors). There can be more than one class value, in which case in the html they will be class="value1 value 2".  I have used only 1 of these possibly multi-valued class values. I have used them because it is nice and easy to read, modern parsers are optimized for css, and there is lots of flexibility with css selector lists. `find[_all]` is still useful and it is easy to convert the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, QHarr. I've actually been watching some videos on CSS selectors to get a better understanding as I'd like to use this approach moving forward. Appreciate your help and time!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by @QHarr you should avoid dynamic identifier similar to his approach the selection comes via `:-soup-contains()` and the known text of the element:

```
soup.select('div:has(>div>span:-soup-contains("Biggest Gainers")) ~ div')
```

To extract the texts I used `stripped_strings` and zipped it with the keys to a `dict`:

```
dict(zip(['rank','name','alias','change'],e.stripped_strings))
```

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
soup=BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content)
data = []
for e in soup.select('div:has(>div>span:-soup-contains("Biggest Gainers")) ~ div'):
    data.append(dict(zip(['rank','name','alias','change'],e.stripped_strings)))
```

###### Output

```
[{'rank': '1', 'name': 'Tenset', 'alias': '10SET', 'change': '1406.99'},
 {'rank': '2', 'name': 'Burn To Earn', 'alias': 'BTE', 'change': '348.89'},
 {'rank': '3', 'name': 'MetaCars', 'alias': 'MTC', 'change': '332.05'}]
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, not too familiar with best practices yet!

While I find both QHarr and your posts very helpful (with this one being very concise and neat!), I'm having trouble understanding the target values you've used in the select() function. I may have to familiarize myself with it a bit better. 

Also noticed that no-one used the find() or find_all() - would you suggest veering away from using it?

Comment: You could also use `find()` and `find_all()` but the readability as well as the flexibility of using `css selectors` is much better in my opinion - it is definitely worth learning.